# Renaming a fastq file in BaseSpace

Tags: fastq

How can I remame a specific fastq file on BaseSpace? Either on CLI or in the web interface.

For instance, rename the file WGS-39857-Long_S107_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz to WGS-39857_S107_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlvO4.png)

Tried search in in the Basespace CLI  manual (https://developer.basespace.illumina.com/docs/content/documentation/cli/cli-overview#CommandDiscovery) and asking ChatGPT but got no working solution